# Android Change the color of List view Item

Tags: android, android-listview

```
   final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                    itemlist, R.layout.listview_custom_view_sales_products,
                    new String[] { "Number", "item_name", "qty" }, new int[] {
                            R.id.number, R.id.Name, R.id.value }) {

                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                    HashMap<String, String> obj = (HashMap<String, String>) getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position);



                for (String x : added_items) {

                      if (String.valueOf(x).equals(obj.get("item_name").toString())) {

                            Log.i("sdsds", "working");

                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                        }

                    } 

                    return view;

                };
            };
```

Here I used the above code to color items according to the items included in ***addeditem***(it is array).But my problem is that it changes the color of the other row views which were not newly added in my wArrayList.

Comment: You're iterating through the whole list of item data for each VIEW. Sooner or later you will find one that matches the condition. You need to get the data item corresponding to `position` parameter. Check DiegoAlts answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do:

```
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                String word=yourArrayOfStrings[position];
                if(word.equals("item_...")){
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                }
                return view;
            }
```

Comment: Add an else statement where you're setting the background to null or some default value. Otherwise when the view is recycled, the background color will remain blue.

Comment: Actually my Array has only the item values that should be colored on List View Item.