# change color of ListView of item that matches some word in ArrayList

Tags: android

```
final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                    itemlist, R.layout.listview_custom_view_sales_products,
                    new String[] { "Number", "item_name", "qty" }, new int[] {
                            R.id.number, R.id.Name, R.id.value }) {

                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


                    return view;

                };
            };
```

I created above code to display item on a list view.But i need to change the color of some item that matches some word in ArrayList.eg=I have 5 items on arrayList and i need to color the items in list that matches words in arrayList

Comment: you need to create custom listadapter. Customize that adapter.

Comment: Why have you asked the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372920/android-change-the-color-of-list-view-item

Reporting this instance.